# How to add image/icon in menu item on pysimplegui

Tags: python, python-3.x, menu, pysimplegui

I am using PySimplegui for UI development,want to know if there is a way to add menu icon as shown in the image below
this can be done with Tkinter and is working fine ,but i am failed to find any references in pysimplegui
any reference or link would be a great help

[image]
expecting this in menu item (image side by text)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's complex to add icons to menu items.

Here, add icons to menu items one by one by tkinter code.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

sg.theme('LightGreen')

menu_def = [
    ['&File', ['&Open     Ctrl-O', '&Save       Ctrl-S', '&Properties', 'E&xit']],
    ['&Edit', ['&Paste', ['Special', 'Normal', ], 'Undo', 'Options::this_is_a_menu_key'], ],
    ['&Toolbar', ['---', 'Command &1', 'Command &2',
                  '---', 'Command &3', 'Command &4']],
    ['&Help', ['&About...']]
]


layout = [
    [sg.Menu(menu_def, key='-MENUBAR-')],
    [sg.Output(size=(60, 10))],
]

window = sg.Window("Title", layout, finalize=True)

images = []

# Menu 1 - File
for i in range(4):
    image = sg.tk.PhotoImage(data=sg.EMOJI_BASE64_HAPPY_LIST[0:4][i])
    images.append(image)
    window['-MENUBAR-'].widget.children['!menu'].entryconfigure(i, image=image, compound='left')

# Menu 2 - Edit
for i in range(3):
    image = sg.tk.PhotoImage(data=sg.EMOJI_BASE64_HAPPY_LIST[4:7][i])
    images.append(image)
    window['-MENUBAR-'].widget.children['!menu2'].entryconfigure(i, image=image, compound='left')

# Menu 2 - Edit - Paste
for i in range(2):
    image = sg.tk.PhotoImage(data=sg.EMOJI_BASE64_HAPPY_LIST[7:9][i])
    images.append(image)
    window['-MENUBAR-'].widget.children['!menu2'].children['!menu'].entryconfigure(i, image=image, compound='left')

# Menu 3 - Toolbar
for i, j in enumerate((1, 2, 4, 5)):
    image = sg.tk.PhotoImage(data=sg.EMOJI_BASE64_HAPPY_LIST[9:13][i])
    images.append(image)
    window['-MENUBAR-'].widget.children['!menu3'].entryconfigure(j, image=image, compound='left')

# Menu 4 - Help
for i in range(1):
    image = sg.tk.PhotoImage(data=sg.EMOJI_BASE64_HAPPY_LIST[13])
    images.append(image)
    window['-MENUBAR-'].widget.children['!menu4'].entryconfigure(i, image=image, compound='left')

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event in (sg.WIN_CLOSED, 'Exit'):
        break
    print(event, values)

window.close()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly what you are looking for, but consider another possibility. You can put Unicode characters in the menu label. For example, you can use  for the Save All menu label, and  for the Reload All from Disk menu label. The trick is finding an appropriate image for other menu labels which can require a bit of creativity.